# The new Chrome won't open the development tools

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I upgraded my Chrome browser 6 Apr 2019 and the new browser won't open the development tools. I have tried right-clicking on the page and selecting 'inspect', have tried

> More tools -> Developer tools'

and I have tried pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and pasting in:

> "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs

But no luck, I have even tried 'System restore' to set the computer back to a time when Chrome developer tools worked. Chrome stopped working. I re-installed the latest Chrome browser, but still no development tools );

It's probably something simple but I can't find it, so if anyone could help I would really appreciate it. This isn't about 'disabled by website' as I have tried simple HTML pages written on my own computer as well.

Have found I can open dev tools in Guest Window (press the user icon at the top right of the browser and choose: Open Guest Window
developer tools open fine but only when Open Guest Window is used.
Have tried creating other users but the dev tools won`t open in them either. Can only see dev tools in guest mode.
Could it be a setting in the browser settings

Comment: Since I updated the chrome browser developer tools won`t open for the ùser`I am using.
BUT they open fine when Open Guest Window is used.
Have tried creating other users but the dev tools won`t open in them either. Can only see dev tools in guest mode.
Could it be a setting in the browser settings